# React Assign Value If Not Null

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements

When I do below:

```
let ContentAreaHeight = document.getElementById('contentArea').clientHeight;
```

I get `Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of null` error, first time page loads, It's normal for me to get this error. So, I am trying to come up with a null check and assign value if not null like with one of the options below, but neither works, stil gives same error.

option1

```
let ContentAreaHeight = (document.getElementById('contentArea').clientHeight) || 0;
```

option2

```
let ContentAreaHeight = (document.getElementById('contentArea').clientHeight !== null) ?
                    document.getElementById('contentArea').clientHeight : 0;
```

I searched this many places found no solution, it seems to be easy but nothing really works..

I am placing this code between
`const content = ({ pageURL, dataStatus }) => {`
and
    `return (`

Comment: Seems as if you're trying to get the height of the content area before it has fully rendered.

Comment: Correct, how can I get the value after it's rendered? Do I have to use lifecycles? it would mean to change my functional component to a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below if the best approach I've found:

```
let ContentArea = document.getElementById('contentArea');
let ContentAreaHeight = 0;
if(ContentArea != null & ContentArea > 0)
     ContentAreaHeight = ContentArea.clientHeight;
```

make sure to place it inside `componentWillUnmount()` as well as `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycles.

Answer (score 0):

You should check prior to calling `.clientHeight`

```
let ContentAreaHeight = document.getElementById('contentArea');
if (ContentAreaHeight) ContentAreaHeight = ContentAreaHeight.clientHeight
```

Comment: Well this works without error, but value ends up being 0.. It should be because by the time page reads `let ContentAreaHeight` its value is 0.. I feel like I need to use it inside `componentWillUnmount()` lifecycle to get the value of the content area?... but I have a simple functional component to render the page `const content `, do I really have to change it to full grown component with lifecycles just for this?

Comment: I think that is a separate issue you might have to ask a different question about. The reason you were getting the error above is because you were doing an assignment on a null value- and null values don't have property values

Comment: My question above has it's own answer, and it's simple for future readers. The best aproach is to get value of the area once the page loads because until then it may change. Also if it gets updated, you need to take that into consideration too. Therefore, this page must be converted to full class.